# Leave application for "days in the past" and "future"

Tags: writing, academic-writing

As we know there are two types of **leave application:**

1. **Asking for leave of absence for days that have passed, ie, writing after being absent.**
2. **Leave of absence for days that are yet to come, ie, writing before being absent.**

But being a learner, I use the sentence:

> **Kindly grant me a leave of absence for the days aforementioned.**

in both the case, ie, **1 and 2.**

Is it natural?

Is the phrase **"leave of absence"** can be used in both the cases?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "aforementioned" means "already mentioned", ie already described in the application. It can be for days already taken or for days still to be taken.

Comment: If it's an imaginary situation, the phrase seems reasonable for both cases. It it's real, then the employer will probably have some standard format and language for leave requests.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Yes, I am talking about generic letters. By the way, are there any formal names for the two different kinds of letters?

Comment: @user100323 Leave for time taken in the past might be called "retroactive leave". Beyond that, I  have no idea.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty so my sentence is perfect when I am talking about generic letters for both the cases?

Comment: I agree with the answer that said your examples are stiff and formal. What you should use with a particular employer depends on the custom there. They may have an entirely different policy about reclassifying absent time in the past as "leave of absence".

Answer (score 2):

**Leave of absence** is an expression meaning permission to be absent.

We don't talk about **a** leave of absence (British English) - just **leave of absence**.

If you wish to be away from your place of employment, you would normally just ask **for leave** (or **to take leave**), rather than leave of absence.

Assuming that your employer has already agreed your leave entitlement, you would normally ask/apply to take leave from X day to Y day, whether for your total leave entitlement or just a portion of it.

If you are due leave for a period when you continued to work without taking the leave you were entitled to, for example the previous year, you might say that you are owed (retrospective) leave for the period concerned and that you wish to take it from X day to Y day (or to be paid in lieu of leave).

Your suggestion: **Kindly grant me leave of absence for the days aforementioned** is rather formal. Prefer: **May I take (retrospective?) leave (for the two week period) from x date to y date?**

Comment: At least in AmE, we “request leave” or “request **a** leave of absence”.

Comment: Never having heard the expression used with the article, I Ngrammed (?) it. As you say, it features - roughly half as popular. More interestingly, from the mid 19th to the mid 20th century, the expression with the article was way behind but has remained relatively steady while the usage **leave of absence** has declined sharply.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&corpus=26&year_start=1800&content=leave+of+absence%2Ca+leave+of+absence&year_end=2019

Comment: In the mid-atlantic US, we generally just say "take leave".  If "of absence" is added, there much be the article 'a', but this sounds too formal / stilted.  We "take leave", and if we want to specify, "take personal leave" or "take sick leave".  Someone who is not present because of this is "out on leave".

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you’re asking about BrE, but I’ll address AmE here for completeness since the usage seems to be quite different.

In AmE, “leave” or “a leave of absence” is only used for extended periods, typically without pay unlike “sick days” or “vacation”. This *must* be requested in advance. If you don’t show up to work for a week or more without any contact, you will typically be fired *in absentia*, so requesting leave afterward is not a possibility.

Some requests for leave cannot be denied, such as family leave (which includes what was formerly called maternity leave), medical leave and military leave; employees are required by law to grant these and hold your job for your return, but you still have to formally request them before you go for those protections to apply.

Other requests for leave, such as “personal leave” or a sabbatical, are at the employer’a discretion, and they typically will not grant these requests unless you make them far enough in advance that they can arrange for someone else to cover your work.

The last category is “administrative leave”, which is due to a policy that prohibits you from doing your job while an investigation is underway, and does include pay since you are *presumed* innocent. For instance, after a police shooting, the officers involved will be placed on administrative leave while the shooting is investigated.

Comment: I don't think this is different across the pond.   It's unacceptably non-professional everywhere to just not show up for work without indicating you will not be there.

Comment: @BadZen Most employers will tolerate a sick day or two without notice if you have a decent reason why you couldn’t call, such being hospitalized after a car accident. The difference is AmE can’t call this “leave”.

Comment: Working for the US government, there are two kinds of leave: annual leave (vacation time), and sick leave (time allowed for sickness); both are limited to a maximum amount in a calendar year. If permitted, annual leave can be used in amounts as short as a day or as long as the yearly maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment, posted as an answer, as I still have insufficient reputation to comment.
There is an acronym colloquially used referring to a missing person or object. "AWOL" , frequently written in capital letters, is a short form for "Absent WithOut Leave". It has military origin, as it indicated a soldier absent without a formal permission.